# M2 InstallData add custom customer attribute (dropdown)

Tags: magento2, customer, custom-attributes

I have a **InstallData.php** which adds a custom customer attribute and everything works fine. In the backend I have an input field.

Now I would prefer to have a **drop down select** instead of the input field.

Can anyone tell me how to modify my InstallData?

```
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config as EavConfig;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * InstallData constructor.
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     * @param EavConfig $eavConfig
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, EavConfig $eavConfig)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $attributeCode = 'my_code';

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, $attributeCode, [
           'label' => 'My Code',
           'required' => 0,
           'user_defined' => 1,
           'system' => 0,
           'position' => 120,
        ]);
        $eavSetup->addAttributeToSet(
          CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
          CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER,
          null,
          $attributeCode
        );
        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, $attributeCode);
        $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', [
           'adminhtml_customer',
        ]);
        $attribute->getResource()->save($attribute);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this to add the select box

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,$attributeCode, [
'type' => 'varchar',
'label' => 'My Code',
'input' => 'select',
'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
'required' => false,
'visible' => true,
'user_defined' => true,
'sort_order' => 101,
'position' => 101,
'system' => 0,
'option' =>
    array (
        'values' =>
            array (
                0 => 'option 1',
                1 => 'option  2',
                2 => 'option  3',
            ),
    ),
]);
```

Comment: how to delete existing attribute for getting updated dropdown ?